# SonarQube exclude rules based on Java version per module in multi-module project

Tags: java, sonarqube

we have a (Maven) multi-module project that uses two different Java versions (some modules use Java 8, some modules use Java 17). The issue that we are running into now is that the configured rule-set contains rules that only apply to Java 9 and above. Since the sonar analysis is running on the entire project, we get violations in the Java 8 modules for Java9+ rules, which are in that way not possible to fix.

Is there a way to configure the sonar analysis to apply different rulesets to different modules within the same project, or to only apply a certain subset of the ruleset to a module, depending on its configured java version?

Answer (score 0):

The better approach will be:

Update the module that is using Java 8 to Java 17.
All the feature of Java 8 will be compatible to Java 17. Later on, you can work on deprecated class of Java 8.

Comment: There are Features in Java 8 that are not only deprecated but even fully removed in Java 17. Also for external libraries this is also not always the case.